# Varnish and expire module adding starts with on regular expressions

Tags: caching, proxies

I have varnish running with the expire module that sends bans into varnish when an article is published. The problem is that it doesn't expire all versions of an article. Some articles could be expired using something like "article-title$" but whats happening is my bans look more like "^/article-title$" which is not matching all the different urls that could possibly be related to the same article.

Can anyone help me understand how can I use the expire module but remove the starts with part of the regular expression from the ban.

here is an example of the bans i am seeing in ban.list

obj.http.x-host ~ www.mysite.com && obj.http.x-url ~ ^/$|^/node/195888/edit$|^/front$|^/node/195888$|^/another-test-article$|^/taxonomy/term/18841$|^/articles$

the problem being "^/another-test-article$" I would like it to be "another-test-article$" instead so that it will match any links that end with that particular pattern.

Thank you